# UIScrollView does not scroll or scrolls partially when running on different device swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have created a view with UIScrollView. When I try to scroll down, it works differently on different devices. I figured out this is because of the different screen size of the device. I'm using `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(325, scrollView.frame.height)` to set the scrollview height.

I came across this when I was trying to find a solution for my problem

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
```

But this doesn't work for me as my scrollview consists of many subviews, labels and buttons of different sizes with different positions. I did all the designing of the scrollview on the storyboard and I didn't use auto-layout.

I need to get the exact height of the scrollview with respect to the device it is running on. Is there any straight forward and easy way to implement this? If not, I'd like to know what I have to do to get the desired height. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the scrollview's contentSize with it's frame/bounds. The frame of the scrollview should be matched to the bounds of the device screen you're running on. The contentSize should be the "virtual canvas" size, that is, the size of your "many subviews, labels and buttons of different sizes with different positions". That should never change, because you want the scrollview to be able to scroll to show all of it no matter what the actual size of the device is. I'd use autolayout to extend the edges of the scrollview to the edges of its superview. You will have to set contentSize explicitly in code though, unfortunately there's no way to do it in the storyboard editor.

Comment: I arranged the subviews, buttons and labels in the storyboard. I'm doing the rest in the code. The scrollview is matched to the bounds of the device as you said. You say the contentSize should never change, but the contentSize doesn't remain constant in different devices. I have to change the contentSize in the code every time I build it on a new device or it doesn't scroll in the desired manner.

Comment: I'm confused. If you arrange the controls in the storyboard then you should know the contentSize based on that. If you're moving them around in code based on the size of the frame, then you should be able to figure out contentSize after you've done your layout. That code snippet should work providing you run it after all the subviews are on the scrollview. What is it returning, and what do you think it should return?

Comment: The width and height of the scrollview are 325 and 800 on the storyboard. If I set the content size to that, it scrolls properly when I build it on iphone 4s and does not work when I run it on devices with larger screen size like iphone 6 and 6 plus. I also checked that the scrollView.frame.height was returning different values on different devices. It returned 712 on an iPhone 4s and returned 968 on iPhone 6s Plus.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? It doesn't scroll? Are you sure the contentSize is larger than the frame.size? That's the only reason I can think of that a scrollview won't scroll.